# How to let the user decide how many threads/tasks he wants to run?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, bots

im programming a little Sneaker-Bot in python with selenium and im already finished with the main part. The last two parts i need to programm are, how i can let the user input his Usernames and Passwords for his Accounts in one text file or i heard that a json file would be good too, how i can acces this data with the programm and finally, how i can let the user create threads/tasks with a specific Username and Password for each thread. I hope you can understand my english and maybe there are some guys under you, that can help me with the last part.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the usernames and passwords from a file, you can just use:

```
f = open(path_to_file)
infolist = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

This will put a new item in the list for every line in the file, meaning you just have to put the usernames and passwords each on their own line. Be careful because putting passwords in a text file is generally not very secure, so make sure you are aware of the risks.

As for the second part, I would create a list that can be filled with threads using a for loop, the range of which is specified by the user input. Then during the iteration, give the "args" argument certain items of the credentials list that are needed for its task. Example below:

```
from threading import *

def spawnScraper(username, password):
    print(f'{username} and {password}')
    ## run the instance here

def main():
    #f = open(path_to_file)
    #infolist = f.readlines()
    #f.close()
    # ^ above code to retrieve data from file
    infolist = ['user1', 'pass1', 'user2', 'pass2']  # using for demonstration
    threadnum = int(input('num >>> '))

    threads = []  # create list to store threads

    for threaditem in range(threadnum):
        uname = infolist[threaditem*2]  # get information from infolist
        pword = infolist[threaditem*2+1]
        threads.append(Thread(target=spawnScraper, args=[uname, pword]))  # create thread
        threads[-1].start()  # start thread

main()
```

Make sure to uncomment the file opening section for actual intergration into your program. If you have any other questions, be sure to comment below.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. To the second part, could you give me an example for that? And actually i was asking the wrong question, because before i can think about how the user could run all of the tasks he made, i have to figure out how to let the user create tasks and how to save them...Actually i will research the whole thing, i must get the thread module better known, before i can ask specific questions.

Comment: No worries, I'll see if I can make a prototype system like you specified.

Comment: Wow thank you very much! That looks already really good even if i dont understand a view parts, because i never saw them before. So do i understand it correctly, that the user can decide how many threads he wants to start, even when there are no username and password for every thread? So basically i need a programm, where the user can choose to make a new thread and where the user can give the thread specific login data that will only be used by that one thread. Furthermore the user should be able to input a size like 40, or 39 and the productpage, the code that will work with the sizenumber

Comment: ,the productpage and the login data is already finished by me, i only need different threads that will run that code with the different size, login data and productpage. And would it be possible to save the made threads in a file or something, so the user dont have to create new tasks/threads, everytime he runs the script again?

Comment: Well in its current form, the code would error if more threads are requested than the amount of credentials, however you could populate the text file with "None" or similar if you want certain threads to not need credentials. As for saving threads, I don't believe it is possible except maybe with the "pickle" module (have a look if you want). Also, if you want the product page info bundled in the text file, just put them above the usernames and account for the change in the function definition, the args list and change the "threaditem*2" to "threaditem*3". Any other questions, just comment. :)

Comment: Thanks again! I will take a look at the pickle module right now.